# How to change widget languge on Disqus?

Tags: javascript, disqus

Anybody, how can I change language of Disqus widgets?
Comment area is fine.
Iserted this before calling the widget, but it's not working:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var disqus_config = function () { 
this.language = "hu";
};  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Disqus 2012 has a huge bug that inhibits language changes—from what I've read online. I tried that same code you tried and also changing the language setting in Settings > General > Language. What worked for me was deleting that code you have, setting Language, and disabling Disqus 2012.

[image]

Try that out, if you haven't already!